# Array and Select Options

Tags: javascript

I have the following code working together with a script that populates fields on autocomplete.

What I would like to do is instead of having an autocomplete text box - use the city field in a drop down / select option field so instead of the user typing the city they select from the drop down.

```
$cities = array(
    array('city'=>'New York', state=>'NY', zip=>'10001'),
    array('city'=>'Los Angeles', state=>'CA', zip=>'90001'),
    array('city'=>'Chicago', state=>'IL', zip=>'60601'),
    array('city'=>'Houston', state=>'TX', zip=>'77001'),
    array('city'=>'Phoenix', state=>'AZ', zip=>'85001'),
    array('city'=>'Philadelphia', state=>'PA', zip=>'19019'),
    array('city'=>'San Antonio', state=>'TX', zip=>'78201'),
    array('city'=>'Dallas', state=>'TX', zip=>'75201'),
    array('city'=>'San Diego', state=>'CA', zip=>'92101'),
    array('city'=>'San Jose', state=>'CA', zip=>'95101'),
    array('city'=>'Detroit', state=>'MI', zip=>'48201'),
    array('city'=>'San Francisco', state=>'CA', zip=>'94101'),
    array('city'=>'Jacksonville', state=>'FL', zip=>'32099'),
    array('city'=>'Indianapolis', state=>'IN', zip=>'46201'),
    array('city'=>'Austin', state=>'TX', zip=>'73301'),
    array('city'=>'Columbus', state=>'OH', zip=>'43085'),
    array('city'=>'Fort Worth', state=>'TX', zip=>'76101'),
    array('city'=>'Charlotte', state=>'NC', zip=>'28201'),
    array('city'=>'Memphis', state=>'TN', zip=>'37501'),
    array('city'=>'Baltimore', state=>'MD', zip=>'21201'),
);
```

// Cleaning up the term
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));

// Rudimentary search
$matches = array();
foreach($cities as $city){
    if(stripos($city['city'], $term) !== false){
        // Add the necessary "value" and "label" fields and append to result set
        $city['value'] = $city['city'];
        $city['label'] = "{$city['city']}, {$city['state']} {$city['zip']}";
        $matches[] = $city;
    }
}

// Truncate, encode and return the results
$matches = array_slice($matches, 0, 5);
print json_encode($matches);

And the following is my script:

```
  Drupal.behaviors.mywebform = {
attach: function (context, settings) {
    var ac_config = {
        source: "/devtest/sites/democities.php",
        select: function(event, ui){
            $("#edit-submitted-info-city").val(ui.item.city);
            $("#edit-submitted-info-state").val(ui.item.state);
            $("#edit-submitted-info-zip").val(ui.item.zip);
        },
        minLength:1
    };
    $("#edit-submitted-info-city").autocomplete(ac_config);
  }};
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

probably not really drupal realated. But here you go:

```
Drupal.behaviors.mywebform = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'/devtest/sites/democities.php',
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( json ) {
            // if #edit-submitted-info-city is not a select you will have to make it one, or take the select that is in, or create one select in it.
            $('#edit-submitted-info-city').append('<select>').attr('id', 'stackexchangeExample');

            $.each(json, function(i, value) {
                $('#stackexchangeExample').append($('<option>').text(value.city).attr('value', value.city));
            });
        }
    });
}};
```

you might want to make sure that you run this only once, adjust the creation of the select element accordingly. or add a once() implementation

Comment: Thanks but did not work for me. I am assuming to use the above I need to keep the city field as a text and the first line changes the text to a select. When I view this in Firebug I see that the <select> tags are placed AFTER </input> which I believe is not what we want. If I change the field type to a Select Option and add the first value from my php (ie. San Jose) as an option only San Jose shows up as an option. If it matters I am using this in webform.

Comment: this is not realy a drupal question, and you did not provide any source code, feel free to setup an example at https://jsfiddle.net/ than one might have a look. the appending is done at `$('#edit-submitted-info-city').append('<select>'` if you have to empty that element first do so. also make sure your select keeps the name of the input that is beeing replaced.

Comment: how is this not a drupal question when I am using drupal and the webform module? If I create a form outside of drupal and use the code it works fine but in drupal webform is where i have the issue.

Comment: because you are asking questions about javascript and html. I don't know webform, maybe it has a select field itself, than you dont have to modify the autocomplete stuff. the solution I posted earlier should get you in the right direction (if your a developer), if you are only a site builder you probably should ask for this on the webform queue, but I think the will have a select field with options already ready, no need to do anything autocomplete related, like the php + json you posted earlier.

Comment: thanks. what my ultimate goal is to have the user choose the city from a drop down and that would autocomplete the state and zip code field. webform does have its own select field with options available and i can dynamically add options but then i get lost trying to do the autocomplete of the state and zip code field.